# C++ Template specializations for primary, templated, specialised and aliased template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I'm trying to specialize a template to work with both primary types, templated types and specialised/aliased templated types. See the code example below.

It compiles but does not link.

How can I write a template specialization for `zero()` that I can call as `zero<myvec>()` and still be able to also call `zero<double>`, etc.?

Reason is that in my application, I'm not given the size `N` of `myvec`, so I cannot write `zero<vec_t, N>()`, however, I know that `myvec` is a template alias as below and I know the structure of the template etc., just not the sizes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

template<std::size_t N>
using vec_t = std::array<double, N>;

using v_t = std::vector<double>;

using v5_t = vec_t<5>;

// generic declaration
template<typename T> T zero();

// full specialization to double 
template<> double zero() { std::cout << " -> Double\n"; return 0;}
// full specialization to v_t
template<> v_t zero() { std::cout << " -> vector<double>\n"; return v_t{}; };
// full specialization to v5_t
template<> v5_t zero() { std::cout << " -> vec_t<5>\n"; return v5_t{}; };

// attempt at partial specialization to vec_t<N>
template<template<typename T, std::size_t N> typename V, typename T, std::size_t N> V<T, N> zero() {
std::cout << " -> V<T, N>\n";
return V<T, N>{}; 
};
template<template<std::size_t N> typename V, std::size_t N> V<N> zero() {
std::cout << " -> V<N>\n";
return V<N>{};
};


int main() {

  double z1 = zero<double>(); // works

  v_t z2 = zero<v_t>(); // works

  v5_t z3 = zero<v5_t>(); // works

  const std::size_t N = 6;
  vec_t<N> z4 = zero<std::array, double, N >(); // works, but requires full specs of vec_t

  vec_t<N> z5 = zero<vec_t, N>(); // works, but requires N

  using myvec = vec_t<6>;
  myvec z6 = zero<myvec>(); // linker error ! but is what I'd like to write

  return 0;
}
```

You may have a look at [CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/W7Kfjn).

Thanks a lot for your help! (P.S. Solutions up to Cpp17 are fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again for the two excellent answers. I really like the variadic template solution ;-).
Turns out there is a simpler, albeit admittedly less generic, solution to the problem stated without replacing functions with structs. Just add a definition to the generic declaration of zero(), i.e. change

```
template <typename T> T zero();
```

to

```
template <typename T> T zero() {return {};};
```

and the code compiles and runs just fine. I feel a little bit of explanation as to why I do this silly stuff is in order: In my application I mix objects of type Eigen::Matrix, Eigen::Tensor, etc of different sizes (realized through template aliasing) with primary scalar types. Unfortunately, the Eigen types do not come with standard zero-initialisation through `{}` but rather have static setZero() functions. The above solution allows me to use the Eigen specific initialisation as a standard and then fully specialize to the scalar types.

I updated the [CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jM1TT9)

Answer (score 2):

Your looking for partial specialization but partial specialization isn't allowed, for functions, in C++.

But is allowed for classes so, if is acceptable for you substitute the `zero()` template functions with methods inside template classes, you can write something as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

template<std::size_t N>
using vec_t = std::array<double, N>;

using v_t = std::vector<double>;

using v5_t = vec_t<5>;

// generic declaration
template <typename T>
struct zero;

// specializations

template <>
struct zero<double>
 { double operator() () { std::cout << " -> double\n"; return {};} };

template <>
struct zero<v_t>
 { v_t operator() () { std::cout << " -> v_t\n"; return {};} };

template <>
struct zero<v5_t>
 { v5_t operator() () { std::cout << " -> v5_t\n"; return {};} };

template <std::size_t N>
struct zero<vec_t<N>>
 { vec_t<N> operator() () { std::cout << " -> vec_t + N\n"; return {};} };

template <template <std::size_t> class C, std::size_t N>
struct zero<C<N>>
 { C<N> operator() () { std::cout << " -> C + N\n"; return {};} };


int main() {

  double z1 = zero<double>{}(); 

  v_t z2 = zero<v_t>{}();

  v5_t z3 = zero<v5_t>{}();

  constexpr std::size_t N = 6;

  vec_t<N> z4 = zero<std::array<double, N>>{}(); 

  vec_t<N> z5 = zero<vec_t<N>>{}();

  using myvec = vec_t<6>;

  myvec z6 = zero<myvec>{}(); // now works
}
```

Observe that you can't call anymore `zero()` as follows

```
zero<double>();
```

because you have to create an object of the required type, so

```
// .........VV
zero<double>{}();
```

If this is a problem, you can use static methods, so if is OK for you give a name to the method (say `func()`), you can call it as follows

```
zero<double>::func();
```

where the `double` specialization is

```
template <>
struct zero<double>
 { static double func () { std::cout << " -> double\n"; return {};} };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking previously about the partial specialisation for functions is forbidden problem, too. Partial specializations for functions, however, should result in a compile time error, shouldn't it? My code does compile but doesn't link.
Also, note that I'm "specialising" through `using aliases`. As far as I understood, that is transparent to the compiler. To me the transition from `z4` to `z `is already a partial specialization - std:array, double are replaced with vec_t. It seems it should be possible to go the extra step and get rid of N as well.

Comment: @JReichardt - What you have written isn't partial specialization: is overloading. But, that way, you can't call the function as you want (`zero<myvec>`), you have to call as `zero<std::array, double, 6u>()`. The linker error come from the fact that `zero<myvec>()` matches the initial (generic) declaration (so compile) that isn't defined (so the link error).

Comment: It seems I'm confused about the exact differentiation of overloading and specialization. Would you say I'm overloading the return type? Zero() does not take any arguments. Anyway, you're right - defining the generic declaration solves the problem - see below. Thanks again.

Comment: The difference between specialization and overloading isn't simple to explain in a comment... your first three specializations (`double`, `v_t` and `v5_t`) are specialization of the first declaration, that receive a single template parameter (a typename). The following `zero()` (`V<T, N>` and `V<N>`) are based on different template parameters, so doesn't match with the original generic declaration and are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

Following @max66 answer you can keep your original API but delegate the call to a template struct:

```
// generic declaration
template <typename T>
struct zero_s;

// specializations
template <>
struct zero_s<double> {
    double operator() () {
        std::cout << " -> double\n"; return {};
    }
};

template <template <typename T, std::size_t> class C, typename T, std::size_t N>
struct zero_s<C<T, N>> {
    C<Type, N> operator() () {
        std::cout << " -> C<T, Size>, Size = " << N << "\n";
        return {};
    }
};

template <std::size_t N> struct zero_s<vec_t<N>> {
    vec_t<N> operator() () {
        std::cout << " -> vec_t + N: " << N << "\n"; return {};
    }
};
    
// ...    
 
//------------------------------------------------
// generic "zero" - still a free function
//------------------------------------------------
template<typename T, typename... Ts> T zero() {
    return zero_s<T, Ts...>{}();
}
```

See: https://godbolt.org/z/cEcvqK